# How to get my own custom erc20 token from ETH to BSC?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, binance, erc20, binance-smart-chain

Lets say I deployed my own ERC20 token on Ethereum called "MONK" with a balance of 1mil. I want users on Binance to trade with this MONK token as well. Do I need to also deploy the same ERC20 contract onto BSC? with the same balance of 1mil?

All the info I can find online only mentions swapping popular existing tokens, nothing about erc20 tokens that dont yet exist on the destination chain.

How can I bridge my own custom ERC20 token from Ethereum to Binance Smart Chain?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I bridge my own custom ERC20 token from Ethereum to Binance Smart Chain?

You can use one of the popular bridges. Some require your token to be listed on Binance exchange (Binance's own bridge). I belive [xDai bridge](https://bridge.xdaichain.com/) is free.

To understand what crosschain bridges are and what are the tradeoffs [watch this bridge presentation to by James Prestwich](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQJWMiX4hT0).